# How can you debug an EOF error that doesn't say what the issue is (only where)?

Tags: python, neo4j, google-colaboratory, sparql, eof

I'm trying to run through this python tutorial about knowledge graphs/information extraction using Neo4j but can't seem to get the last chunk to run and it's driving me crazy! I've been following along with this tutorial: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/extract-knowledge-from-text-end-to-end-information-extraction-pipeline-with-spacy-and-neo4j-502b2b1e0754

The entire script is provided in their link to a Google Colab. I also encountered some earlier problems but were able to fix those (so I'm guessing this tutorial is a little out of date--even though it's only from May). For example, I had to change every instance of:

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
    'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=' + 
      sparql,
```

to this:

```
CALL apoc.load.jsonParams(
    'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=' + 
      apoc.text.urlencode(sparql),
```

I also had to add in this line to be able to get everything to merge correctly:

```
  FOREACH(ignoreme in case when row['label'] is not null then [1] else [] end |
```

Here is the copy of the Colab that reflects this updated code if that's helpful for anyone to play around with: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hq9gbWnq_V3n9_3Hn2krXoHGsJQDPD0p?usp=sharing

I've tried to Google the error and have figured out (I think) that is has something to do with a closure issue (of quotes/brackets/etc.) but can't figure out what!! I repeatedly get the error:

```
DatabaseError: {code: Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError} {message: Lexical error at line 22, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""}
```

So I know it's something about that last line but saying it was encountered after "" is not helpful...

Comment: which version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: ? And exactly which cell is causing the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using neo4j-5.0.1

Comment: the very last chunk is where i get the error

Comment: @TomažBratanič ^

Comment: Neo4j 5 is not even released, so either you have some insider connections or you don't have that version

Comment: @TomažBratanič I honestly have no idea then....whatever currently automatically downloads then when you install it then I guess (whatever that is)?